# Python: How to move items (?popped) from one list to a second list, initially blank list

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, this is a self-improvement exercise to learn Python coding so I can get into some level of test automation.  Creating a GO FISH game.  I have a fresh deck of cards, which I've shuffled.

Post-Shuffled Freshdeck is: ['6D', '9S', 'AS', '2D', 'QH', 'JD', '7D', '6C', '7S', '4D', 'JS', '9D', '8S', '9C', 'AD', '2C', '8D', 'QC', 'KC', '10D', 'QD', 'KD', 'JC', '7C', 'QS', 'KS', '10S', 'KH', 'AC', '3H', '3D', '10C', '8H', '5C', '2H', '4C', '6H', '10H', '8C', 'JH', '2S', '4S', '3C', '6S', '4H', '5S', '9H', '5D', '7H', '3S', 'AH', '5H']

I want to deal out 7 cards to each player, so I need to pop last card from said list and move it a new list for each player.  (Reading other places has suggested a dict for hold the list of player hands).  That isn't the basic issue.  No matter how to try to use append, I can't seem to get the last value to be stored in the new(orginally blank list on first iteration).  Popping a value works just fine.  My shuffled deck reduces in size every execution, but I lose the last value to space.

```
def create_hand(PN,shuffled_deck):
    print("Create Hand Function")
    print("Creating Hand of Cards for Player: ",PN)
    print("Length of Shuffled Pre-Shuffled Deck is: ",len(shuffled_deck))
    print("Pre-Shuffled Freshdeck is:",shuffled_deck)
    random.shuffle(shuffled_deck)
    print("Post-Shuffled Freshdeck is:",shuffled_deck)

    for i in range(1,7,1):
        print(f"The {i}th card number will be popped to Player Hand {PN}")
        temp=[]
        print("Printing Temp  ",temp)
        print(shuffled_deck)
        temp.append(print(shuffled_deck[-1]))
        shuffled_deck.pop(-1)
```

Comment: Remove the print in `temp.append(print(shuffled_deck[-1])) ` it shall be `temp.append(shuffled_deck[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

`pop` returns the popped object.

So all you need to do is `temp.append(shuffled_deck.pop(-1))`

This way you will pop the object and immediately append it to temp.

If you also want to print it, you can do so before popping:

```
print(shuffled_deck[-1])
temp.append(shuffled_deck.pop(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation.  `print` is misused here; it does not return a value.  `pop` returns the value.

```
    temp.append(print(shuffled_deck[-1]))   # Print the value and put a `None` into the player's hand
    shuffled_deck.pop(-1)                   # Remove the value at the end of the list and toss it away.
```

Try:

```
temp.append(shuffled_deck.pop(-1))
```

For better program flow, simply pull off the entire hand.  Dealing is merely one last "randomization" technique for human frailties.

```
temp = shuffled_deck[:7]
shuffled_deck = shuffled_deck[7:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Prune.  Works perfectly.  Returned the "new" shuffled deck to the previous function and was then able to continue dealing to next player.